# Foreach em arquivo JSON

Tags: php, json

Tenho um retorno `JSON`, mas não estou conseguindo fazer um `foreach` (PHP) nele, fica dando esse erro:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Segue abaixo o `JSON`:

```
{
  "categorias": {
    "categoria": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Chás e Ervas",
        "subcategorias": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "nome": "Chás",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "nome": "Chimarrão",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Condimentos e Especiarias",
        "subcategorias": [
          {
            "id": "3",
            "nome": "Azeites",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "nome": "Caldos",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "5",
            "nome": "Conservas",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "nome": "Diet e Light",
        "subcategorias": [
          {
            "id": "6",
            "nome": "Açaí e Guaraná",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "7",
            "nome": "Adoçantes",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Esse é o JSON, certo? E o seu código PHP, pode postá-lo?

Answer (score 1):

Para ler esse [json](/questions/tagged/json) seria dessa forma:

Exemplo ***minimo***:

```
$dados = json_decode($json);    

foreach ($dados->categorias->categoria as $c) 
{
    echo $c->id;
    echo ' - ';
    echo $c->nome;
    echo '<br>';
    foreach ($c->subcategorias as $s) 
    {
        echo ' - ' . $s->id;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $s->nome;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $s->descricao;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

}
```

```
$dados = json_decode($json);


foreach ($dados->categorias->categoria as $c) 
{
    echo $c->id;
    echo ' - ';
    echo $c->nome;
    echo '<br>';
    foreach ($c->subcategorias as $s) 
    {
        echo ' - ' . $s->id;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $s->nome;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $s->descricao;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

}
```

---

Código ***completo***:

```
<?php 

$json = '{
  "categorias": {
    "categoria": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Chás e Ervas",
        "subcategorias": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "nome": "Chás",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "nome": "Chimarrão",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Condimentos e Especiarias",
        "subcategorias": [
          {
            "id": "3",
            "nome": "Azeites",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "nome": "Caldos",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "5",
            "nome": "Conservas",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "nome": "Diet e Light",
        "subcategorias": [
          {
            "id": "6",
            "nome": "Açaí e Guaraná",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          },
          {
            "id": "7",
            "nome": "Adoçantes",
            "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}';


$dados = json_decode($json);


foreach ($dados->categorias->categoria as $c) 
{
    echo $c->id;
    echo ' - ';
    echo $c->nome;
    echo '<br>';
    foreach ($c->subcategorias as $s) 
    {
        echo ' - ' . $s->id;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $s->nome;
        echo ' - ';
        echo $s->descricao;
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Valeu Virgilio, vou testar aqui.